# A damped wave equation with non null BC

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Do exist any physical interpretation for the following wave equation with non null boundary conditions $ y=g \ne 0 $ on $\partial \Omega :$

$$y_{tt}=\Delta y + a(x) y + b(t)y_t, \;\mbox{in}\; 
\Omega\times (0,T).$$

Thanks!